# Optimizing Spring / Hibernate project for mobile devices

Tags: spring, mobile, spring-mvc

I have to optimize a Spring / Hibernate project (which was created without keeping mobile devices in mind) to be viewed in mobile devices such as iphone.

This project uses Spring MVC tags in the front end. Is it possible to attach a mobile friendly renderer to Spring MVC? (it is possible in JSF)

Otherwise what are the options available to me?

(My intention is to provide a mobile friendly UI for the existing project without changing the backend)

Answer (score 1):

Spring MVC doesn't have tags for UI components that could be rendered differently. It just has low-level tags to render form fields, and messages.

If you want specific pages for the mobile app, you'll have to tweak the CSS, and/or rewrite the pages. It can help you with its [support for themes](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/spring-framework-reference.html#mvc-themeresolver), but you won't find any magic wand that converts an HTML page and give it mobile-friendly aspect.

Comment: Does Spring offer any support (in some form or other) as far as mobile applications development?

Comment: No. Spring is an MVC framework, and doesn't care much how the view is implemented. It supports JSP, FreeMarker, Velocity, etc. and has some helper tags, but what you put in the view is up to you.

Comment: Spring MVC can be used view-agnostic. So you could use a view-resolver that uses a view-technology or view-configuration especially for the mobile view. "Spring MVC tags" implies you use JSP as view technology?

Comment: Yes the project in question uses JSP.